# How to preserve aspect ratio of a SVG symbol?

Tags: html, css, svg

I need to reuse multiple times some SVG icons, to avoid repetition I put them in a `<defs>` tag and reuse them later with `<use>`. However, I want to resize the icons by only defining the height, I expect the width to adapt automatically, but it doesn't work and I can't manage to find any solution. Is there anything possible to make the width dynamic?

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display: none" >
  <defs>
    <symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 384 512">
      <path fill="currentColor" stroke="none" d="m384 192c0 87.4-117 243-168.3 307.2-12.3 15.3-35.1 15.3-47.4 0-52.2-64.2-168.3-219.8-168.3-307.2 0-106.04 85.96-192 192-192 106 0 192 85.96 192 192z"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<!-- Doesn't work, the width is arbitrarily set to 300px. -->
<svg height="1rem">
  <use href="#icon" />
</svg>
```

Comment: `object-fit` in CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, a parent svg can't automatically get the `<symbol>` viewBox values.

So you either need to:

- copy the symbol's viewBox attribute to your `<use>` parent svg
- calculate viewBox via javaScript (querying for referenced symbol instance)
- create aspect-ratio css classes (as suggested by [@Dave Pritlove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834684/how-to-preserve-aspect-ratio-of-a-svg-symbol/72835113#72835113))

#### Example 1: copied viewBox attribute (exact, scaled and rounded)

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display: none" >
    <symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 384 512">
      <path fill="currentColor" stroke="none" d="m384 192c0 87.4-117 243-168.3 307.2-12.3 15.3-35.1 15.3-47.4 0-52.2-64.2-168.3-219.8-168.3-307.2 0-106.04 85.96-192 192-192 106 0 192 85.96 192 192z"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>

<p>Original viewBox values</p>
<svg height="1rem" viewBox="0 0 384 512">
  <use href="#icon" />
</svg>

<p>Upscaled viewBox values</p>
<svg height="1rem" viewBox="0 0 768 1024">
  <use href="#icon" />
</svg>

<p>Scaled down viewBox values</p>
<svg height="1rem" viewBox="0 0 3.84 5.12">
  <use href="#icon" />
</svg>

<p>Rounded</p>
<svg height="1rem" viewBox="0 0 4 5">
  <use href="#icon" />
</svg>
```

Worth mentioning: you don't necessarily need the exact same values. Scaled values will work at well. Rounded values might also be OK for your needs - even though they actually change the precise aspect ratio.

#### Example 2: viewBox attribute retrieved from referenced `<symbol>`

(Will only work with svgs inlined in your HTML body)

```js
let use = document.querySelectorAll('use')

use.forEach(function(el){
  let id = el.getAttribute('href');
  let symbol = document.querySelector(id);
  let viewBox = symbol.getAttribute('viewBox');
  el.closest('svg').setAttribute('viewBox', viewBox );
})
```

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display: none" >
    <symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 384 512">
      <path fill="currentColor" stroke="none" d="m384 192c0 87.4-117 243-168.3 307.2-12.3 15.3-35.1 15.3-47.4 0-52.2-64.2-168.3-219.8-168.3-307.2 0-106.04 85.96-192 192-192 106 0 192 85.96 192 192z"/>
    </symbol>
<symbol id="address-card" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
    <path fill="currentColor" d="M208 256c35.35 0 64-28.65 64-64c0-35.35-28.65-64-64-64s-64 28.65-64 64C144 227.3 172.7 256 208 256zM464 232h-96c-13.25 0-24 10.75-24 24s10.75 24 24 24h96c13.25 0 24-10.75 24-24S477.3 232 464 232zM240 288h-64C131.8 288 96 323.8 96 368C96 376.8 103.2 384 112 384h192c8.836 0 16-7.164 16-16C320 323.8 284.2 288 240 288zM464 152h-96c-13.25 0-24 10.75-24 24s10.75 24 24 24h96c13.25 0 24-10.75 24-24S477.3 152 464 152zM512 32H64C28.65 32 0 60.65 0 96v320c0 35.35 28.65 64 64 64h448c35.35 0 64-28.65 64-64V96C576 60.65 547.3 32 512 32zM528 416c0 8.822-7.178 16-16 16H64c-8.822 0-16-7.178-16-16V96c0-8.822 7.178-16 16-16h448c8.822 0 16 7.178 16 16V416z"></path>
  </symbol>
  
</svg>

<p>Original viewBox values</p>
<svg height="1rem" viewBox="0 0 384 512">
  <use href="#icon" />
</svg>
<svg height="1rem" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
  <use href="#address-card" />
</svg>


<p>Js generated viewBox values</p>
<svg height="1rem">
  <use href="#icon" />
</svg>

<svg height="1rem">
  <use href="#address-card" />
</svg>
```

BTW: `<symbol>` elements don't need to be nested in a `<defs>` since they are invisible by default.

Answer (score 1):

CSS `aspect-ratio` allows you to achieve a consistent ratio when specifying only height or width. In your case, the `aspect-ratio` can be set (in the stylesheet) to the svg `viewbox` ratio:  384/512;

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

Working snippet:

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  aspect-ratio: 384/512;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display: none" >
  <defs>
    <symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 384 512">
      <path fill="currentColor" stroke="none" d="m384 192c0 87.4-117 243-168.3 307.2-12.3 15.3-35.1 15.3-47.4 0-52.2-64.2-168.3-219.8-168.3-307.2 0-106.04 85.96-192 192-192 106 0 192 85.96 192 192z"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<!-- Doesn't work, the width is arbitrarily set to 300px. -->
<svg height="1rem">
  <use href="#icon" />
</svg>
```