# Rendered SVG size differs when using `<use>` vs `<img>`

Tags: html, css, svg

I have two implementations of consuming the same SVG content: one through a `<use>` element and one through an `<img>`. Despite the same content, viewbox, and sizing on both, the `<use>` element comes up shorter -- whereas the `<img>` is `160x160`, `<use>` is `150x122`. For the life of me I cannot seem to find an answer as to why this is.

The problem I'm looking to solve is to merge 10 or so individual SVG files, consumed via an `<img>`, into a singular sprite sheet to avoid unnecessary network requests (they're always consumed together, making this a perfect use for sprites). However, the sizing doesn't match up when switching to the sprite sheet.

> index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            div {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                max-width: 10rem;
            }
            img, svg {
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <svg>
                <use href="./icon-sprite.svg#icon" />
            </svg>
            <img src="./icon.svg" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> icon-sprite.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 54 54">
        <path d="M52 5H2C.9 5 0 5.9 0 7v40c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h50c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zM1 7c0-.55.45-1 1-1h50c.55 0 1 .45 1 1v9H1zm52 40c0 .55-.45 1-1 1H2c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V17h52z" fill="#37474f" />
        <path d="M6 8.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5S5.17 9.5 6 9.5s1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zm6-4a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zm6-4a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zM48 10c0-.55-.45-1-1-1H35c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v2c0 .55.45 1 1 1h12c.55 0 1-.45 1-1zm-1 2H35v-2h12zM29.8 29.58l3.2 2.28V44c0 1.65 1.35 3 3 3s3-1.35 3-3V31.86l3.2-2.28c.44-.32.8-1.03.8-1.58v-5c0-.55-.32-1.32-.7-1.7L39 18v6l-3 2-3-2v-6l-3.3 3.3c-.38.38-.7 1.15-.7 1.7v5c0 .55.36 1.26.8 1.58zM30 23c0-.28.2-.8.4-1l1.6-1.6v4.15l.45.3 3 2 .55.36.56-.37 3-2 .44-.3V20.2l1.6 1.7c.2.2.4.82.4 1.1v5c0 .23-.2.63-.4.77l-3.18 2.27-.42.3V44c0 1.1-.9 2-2 2s-2-.9-2-2V31.34l-.42-.3-3.18-2.27c-.2-.14-.4-.54-.4-.77z" fill="#37474f" />
        <path stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M36 44V33" fill="#b2ff59" stroke="#37474f" stroke-linecap="round" />
        <path d="M27 36h-4V19h-8v17h-4l8 11zm-12 1h1V20h6v17h3.04L19 45.3 12.96 37z" fill="#37474f" />
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

> icon.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 54 54">
    <path d="M52 5H2C.9 5 0 5.9 0 7v40c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h50c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zM1 7c0-.55.45-1 1-1h50c.55 0 1 .45 1 1v9H1zm52 40c0 .55-.45 1-1 1H2c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V17h52z" fill="#37474f" />
    <path d="M6 8.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5S5.17 9.5 6 9.5s1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zm6-4a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zm6-4a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zM48 10c0-.55-.45-1-1-1H35c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v2c0 .55.45 1 1 1h12c.55 0 1-.45 1-1zm-1 2H35v-2h12zM29.8 29.58l3.2 2.28V44c0 1.65 1.35 3 3 3s3-1.35 3-3V31.86l3.2-2.28c.44-.32.8-1.03.8-1.58v-5c0-.55-.32-1.32-.7-1.7L39 18v6l-3 2-3-2v-6l-3.3 3.3c-.38.38-.7 1.15-.7 1.7v5c0 .55.36 1.26.8 1.58zM30 23c0-.28.2-.8.4-1l1.6-1.6v4.15l.45.3 3 2 .55.36.56-.37 3-2 .44-.3V20.2l1.6 1.7c.2.2.4.82.4 1.1v5c0 .23-.2.63-.4.77l-3.18 2.27-.42.3V44c0 1.1-.9 2-2 2s-2-.9-2-2V31.34l-.42-.3-3.18-2.27c-.2-.14-.4-.54-.4-.77z" fill="#37474f" />
    <path stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M36 44V33" fill="#b2ff59" stroke="#37474f" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <path d="M27 36h-4V19h-8v17h-4l8 11zm-12 1h1V20h6v17h3.04L19 45.3 12.96 37z" fill="#37474f" />
</svg>
```

Comment: A svg don't auto-adjust width/height to it's child elements. It doesn't copy the viewBox from the symbol element. See also ["How to preserve aspect ratio of a SVG symbol?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834684/how-to-preserve-aspect-ratio-of-a-svg-symbol/72840877#72840877)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build this into a snippet I had to use an inline SVG for the sprite, to avoid cross-domain security issues. But all I had to do to get the sprite the same size as the image was to add an `aspect-ratio: 1/1`.

Note that neither your `icon.svg` nor your `icon-sprite.svg` have an intrinsic size, so if you do not specify a size, you are relying on the browser default behaviour which may vary from browser to browser. Your CSS specifies the width of the SVGs (100% of a flexbox which is 10em wide), but not the height. I believe the spec does say that a user agent should use a default size for an SVG if the size is not specified. It seems that, in my browser at least, the regular SVG defaults to an aspect-ratio of 1:1 when the height is not specified, whereas the sprite seems to default to zero height.

Not sure why you were getting different results, but it could be browser-dependent. I am using Safari on a Mac. I tried in Chrome also and the sprite doesn’t need the aspect-ratio to be specified manually.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            div {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                max-width: 10rem;
                gap: 1em;
            }
            img, svg {
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg style="display: none">
          <defs>
            <symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 54 54">
              <path d="M52 5H2C.9 5 0 5.9 0 7v40c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h50c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zM1 7c0-.55.45-1 1-1h50c.55 0 1 .45 1 1v9H1zm52 40c0 .55-.45 1-1 1H2c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V17h52z" fill="#37474f" />
              <path d="M6 8.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5S5.17 9.5 6 9.5s1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zm6-4a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zm6-4a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zM48 10c0-.55-.45-1-1-1H35c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v2c0 .55.45 1 1 1h12c.55 0 1-.45 1-1zm-1 2H35v-2h12zM29.8 29.58l3.2 2.28V44c0 1.65 1.35 3 3 3s3-1.35 3-3V31.86l3.2-2.28c.44-.32.8-1.03.8-1.58v-5c0-.55-.32-1.32-.7-1.7L39 18v6l-3 2-3-2v-6l-3.3 3.3c-.38.38-.7 1.15-.7 1.7v5c0 .55.36 1.26.8 1.58zM30 23c0-.28.2-.8.4-1l1.6-1.6v4.15l.45.3 3 2 .55.36.56-.37 3-2 .44-.3V20.2l1.6 1.7c.2.2.4.82.4 1.1v5c0 .23-.2.63-.4.77l-3.18 2.27-.42.3V44c0 1.1-.9 2-2 2s-2-.9-2-2V31.34l-.42-.3-3.18-2.27c-.2-.14-.4-.54-.4-.77z" fill="#37474f" />
              <path stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M36 44V33" fill="#b2ff59" stroke="#37474f" stroke-linecap="round" />
              <path d="M27 36h-4V19h-8v17h-4l8 11zm-12 1h1V20h6v17h3.04L19 45.3 12.96 37z" fill="#37474f" />
            </symbol>
          </defs>
        </svg>

        <div>
            <svg style="aspect-ratio: 1/1; border: 2px solid lime;">
                <use href="#icon" />
            </svg>
            <img style="border: 2px solid cyan;" src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-77582685/icon.svg" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `aspect-ratio: 1/1` absolutely did it, thanks! Using FireFox on Linux for what it's worth. There's still a tiny amount of deviation in sizes that looks to be inherent to SVGs vs img, but close enough!

Comment: Instead of `aspect-ratio: 1/1` for the svg element, a better solution would be using a viewBox attribute. In this case I would have used `viewBox="0 0 54 54"`

Comment: @enxaneta The `<symbol>` itself has the `viewBox` attribute. There's no way for the consumer in this case to have the slightest clue what that value is. `aspect-ratio: 1/1` works, however.

Answer (score -1):

Expanding on enxaneta's comment:

#### `<svg>` elements don't adjust their rendered bounding box based on content

No element will cause the parent svg element to expand its rendered bounding box. (you can retrieve a tight content based bounding box via JS method `getBBox()`)

A common misconception is to think the `<symbol>` element's viewBox is somehow "inherited" to the parent svg when appending a `<use>` instance (referencing to the symbol). Nope! No exception!

This can't work since we can only inherit properties **from parent (svg) to child (use)** and not the other way round (at least in a HTML/CSS context).

If you don't specify either

- width and height or
- a viewBox for the parent `<svg>` element – the browser will render the svg with a default of **300 x 150 px**.

However, if all your icons are placed in a square bounding box you can as well set a css rule to specify a width and height.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}

.icon {
  font-size: 150px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h3>Original icon (default: rendered at 100% width)</h3>
<svg viewBox="0 0 54 54">
  <path d="M52 5H2C.9 5 0 5.9 0 7v40c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h50c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zM1 7c0-.55.45-1 1-1h50c.55 0 1 .45 1 1v9H1zm52 40c0 .55-.45 1-1 1H2c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V17h52z" fill="#37474f" />
  <path d="M6 8.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5S5.17 9.5 6 9.5s1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zm6-4a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zm6-4a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zM48 10c0-.55-.45-1-1-1H35c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v2c0 .55.45 1 1 1h12c.55 0 1-.45 1-1zm-1 2H35v-2h12zM29.8 29.58l3.2 2.28V44c0 1.65 1.35 3 3 3s3-1.35 3-3V31.86l3.2-2.28c.44-.32.8-1.03.8-1.58v-5c0-.55-.32-1.32-.7-1.7L39 18v6l-3 2-3-2v-6l-3.3 3.3c-.38.38-.7 1.15-.7 1.7v5c0 .55.36 1.26.8 1.58zM30 23c0-.28.2-.8.4-1l1.6-1.6v4.15l.45.3 3 2 .55.36.56-.37 3-2 .44-.3V20.2l1.6 1.7c.2.2.4.82.4 1.1v5c0 .23-.2.63-.4.77l-3.18 2.27-.42.3V44c0 1.1-.9 2-2 2s-2-.9-2-2V31.34l-.42-.3-3.18-2.27c-.2-.14-.4-.54-.4-.77z" fill="#37474f" />
  <path stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M36 44V33" fill="#b2ff59" stroke="#37474f" stroke-linecap="round" />
  <path d="M27 36h-4V19h-8v17h-4l8 11zm-12 1h1V20h6v17h3.04L19 45.3 12.96 37z" fill="#37474f" />
</svg>

<h3>No svg dimensions specified (default: 300x150)</h3>
<svg>
  <use href="#icon" />
</svg>

<h3>No symbol viewbox specified (default: 300x150)</h3>
<svg>
  <use href="#iconNoViewBox" />
</svg>

<h3>symbol viewbox default(300x150)</h3>
<svg>
  <use href="#iconDefaultViewBox" />
</svg>


<h3>svg square dimensions specified via css</h3>
<svg class="icon">
  <use href="#icon" />
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position:absolute; width:0; height:0; visibility:hidden">
  <symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 54 54">
    <path d="M52 5H2C.9 5 0 5.9 0 7v40c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h50c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zM1 7c0-.55.45-1 1-1h50c.55 0 1 .45 1 1v9H1zm52 40c0 .55-.45 1-1 1H2c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V17h52z" fill="#37474f" />
    <path d="M6 8.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5S5.17 9.5 6 9.5s1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zm6-4a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zm6-4a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zM48 10c0-.55-.45-1-1-1H35c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v2c0 .55.45 1 1 1h12c.55 0 1-.45 1-1zm-1 2H35v-2h12zM29.8 29.58l3.2 2.28V44c0 1.65 1.35 3 3 3s3-1.35 3-3V31.86l3.2-2.28c.44-.32.8-1.03.8-1.58v-5c0-.55-.32-1.32-.7-1.7L39 18v6l-3 2-3-2v-6l-3.3 3.3c-.38.38-.7 1.15-.7 1.7v5c0 .55.36 1.26.8 1.58zM30 23c0-.28.2-.8.4-1l1.6-1.6v4.15l.45.3 3 2 .55.36.56-.37 3-2 .44-.3V20.2l1.6 1.7c.2.2.4.82.4 1.1v5c0 .23-.2.63-.4.77l-3.18 2.27-.42.3V44c0 1.1-.9 2-2 2s-2-.9-2-2V31.34l-.42-.3-3.18-2.27c-.2-.14-.4-.54-.4-.77z" fill="#37474f" />
    <path stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M36 44V33" fill="#b2ff59" stroke="#37474f" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <path d="M27 36h-4V19h-8v17h-4l8 11zm-12 1h1V20h6v17h3.04L19 45.3 12.96 37z" fill="#37474f" />
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="iconNoViewBox" fill="red">
    <path d="M52 5H2C.9 5 0 5.9 0 7v40c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h50c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zM1 7c0-.55.45-1 1-1h50c.55 0 1 .45 1 1v9H1zm52 40c0 .55-.45 1-1 1H2c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V17h52z" />
    <path d="M6 8.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5S5.17 9.5 6 9.5s1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zm6-4a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zm6-4a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zM48 10c0-.55-.45-1-1-1H35c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v2c0 .55.45 1 1 1h12c.55 0 1-.45 1-1zm-1 2H35v-2h12zM29.8 29.58l3.2 2.28V44c0 1.65 1.35 3 3 3s3-1.35 3-3V31.86l3.2-2.28c.44-.32.8-1.03.8-1.58v-5c0-.55-.32-1.32-.7-1.7L39 18v6l-3 2-3-2v-6l-3.3 3.3c-.38.38-.7 1.15-.7 1.7v5c0 .55.36 1.26.8 1.58zM30 23c0-.28.2-.8.4-1l1.6-1.6v4.15l.45.3 3 2 .55.36.56-.37 3-2 .44-.3V20.2l1.6 1.7c.2.2.4.82.4 1.1v5c0 .23-.2.63-.4.77l-3.18 2.27-.42.3V44c0 1.1-.9 2-2 2s-2-.9-2-2V31.34l-.42-.3-3.18-2.27c-.2-.14-.4-.54-.4-.77z" fill="#37474f" />
    <path stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M36 44V33" fill="#b2ff59" stroke="#37474f" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <path d="M27 36h-4V19h-8v17h-4l8 11zm-12 1h1V20h6v17h3.04L19 45.3 12.96 37z" fill="#37474f" />
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="iconDefaultViewBox" viewBox="0 0 300 150">
    <path d="M52 5H2C.9 5 0 5.9 0 7v40c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h50c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zM1 7c0-.55.45-1 1-1h50c.55 0 1 .45 1 1v9H1zm52 40c0 .55-.45 1-1 1H2c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V17h52z" fill="#37474f" />
    <path d="M6 8.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5S5.17 9.5 6 9.5s1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zm6-4a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zm6-4a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zM48 10c0-.55-.45-1-1-1H35c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v2c0 .55.45 1 1 1h12c.55 0 1-.45 1-1zm-1 2H35v-2h12zM29.8 29.58l3.2 2.28V44c0 1.65 1.35 3 3 3s3-1.35 3-3V31.86l3.2-2.28c.44-.32.8-1.03.8-1.58v-5c0-.55-.32-1.32-.7-1.7L39 18v6l-3 2-3-2v-6l-3.3 3.3c-.38.38-.7 1.15-.7 1.7v5c0 .55.36 1.26.8 1.58zM30 23c0-.28.2-.8.4-1l1.6-1.6v4.15l.45.3 3 2 .55.36.56-.37 3-2 .44-.3V20.2l1.6 1.7c.2.2.4.82.4 1.1v5c0 .23-.2.63-.4.77l-3.18 2.27-.42.3V44c0 1.1-.9 2-2 2s-2-.9-2-2V31.34l-.42-.3-3.18-2.27c-.2-.14-.4-.54-.4-.77z" fill="#37474f" />
    <path stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M36 44V33" fill="#b2ff59" stroke="#37474f" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <path d="M27 36h-4V19h-8v17h-4l8 11zm-12 1h1V20h6v17h3.04L19 45.3 12.96 37z" fill="#37474f" />
  </symbol>

</svg>
```

As long as the aspect ratio stays the same you can also use a generic viewBox.

If a symbol has a viewBox its use reference will be scaled to fit into the parent viewBox.

A symbol without a viewBox is rendered according to its original drawing size.

```css
svg {
  font-size: 10vmin;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h3>Scaled svg use</h3>
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <use href="#icon" />
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <use href="#icon" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <use href="#circle-check" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <use href="#circle-check" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 50 100">
  <use href="#icon" />
</svg>


<h3>No symbol viewBox</h3>
<p>If a symbol has a viewBox its use reference will be scaled to fit into the parent viewBox.</p>
<p>A symbol without a viewBox is rendered according to its original drawing size</p>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 256 256" overflow="visible">
  
<symbol id="circle-check2" class="icon icon-circle-check" overflow="visible">
    <path d="M335 175L224 286.1L176.1 239c-9.375-9.375-24.56-9.375-33.94 0s-9.375 24.56 0 33.94l64 64C211.7 341.7 217.8 344 224 344s12.28-2.344 16.97-7.031l128-128c9.375-9.375 9.375-24.56 0-33.94S344.4 165.7 335 175zM256 0C114.6 0 0 114.6 0 256s114.6 256 256 256s256-114.6 256-256S397.4 0 256 0zM256 464c-114.7 0-208-93.31-208-208S141.3 48 256 48s208 93.31 208 208S370.7 464 256 464z" />
  </symbol>
  
<symbol id="circle-check3" class="icon icon-circle-check" viewBox="0 0 512 512" overflow="visible">
    <path d="M335 175L224 286.1L176.1 239c-9.375-9.375-24.56-9.375-33.94 0s-9.375 24.56 0 33.94l64 64C211.7 341.7 217.8 344 224 344s12.28-2.344 16.97-7.031l128-128c9.375-9.375 9.375-24.56 0-33.94S344.4 165.7 335 175zM256 0C114.6 0 0 114.6 0 256s114.6 256 256 256s256-114.6 256-256S397.4 0 256 0zM256 464c-114.7 0-208-93.31-208-208S141.3 48 256 48s208 93.31 208 208S370.7 464 256 464z" />
  </symbol>
  
    <use href="#circle-check2" />
    <use href="#circle-check3" fill="red" />

</svg>










<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position:absolute; width:0; height:0; visibility:hidden">
  <symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 54 54">
    <path d="M52 5H2C.9 5 0 5.9 0 7v40c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h50c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zM1 7c0-.55.45-1 1-1h50c.55 0 1 .45 1 1v9H1zm52 40c0 .55-.45 1-1 1H2c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V17h52z" fill="#37474f" />
    <path d="M6 8.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5S5.17 9.5 6 9.5s1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zm6-4a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zm6-4a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zm0 4c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zM48 10c0-.55-.45-1-1-1H35c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v2c0 .55.45 1 1 1h12c.55 0 1-.45 1-1zm-1 2H35v-2h12zM29.8 29.58l3.2 2.28V44c0 1.65 1.35 3 3 3s3-1.35 3-3V31.86l3.2-2.28c.44-.32.8-1.03.8-1.58v-5c0-.55-.32-1.32-.7-1.7L39 18v6l-3 2-3-2v-6l-3.3 3.3c-.38.38-.7 1.15-.7 1.7v5c0 .55.36 1.26.8 1.58zM30 23c0-.28.2-.8.4-1l1.6-1.6v4.15l.45.3 3 2 .55.36.56-.37 3-2 .44-.3V20.2l1.6 1.7c.2.2.4.82.4 1.1v5c0 .23-.2.63-.4.77l-3.18 2.27-.42.3V44c0 1.1-.9 2-2 2s-2-.9-2-2V31.34l-.42-.3-3.18-2.27c-.2-.14-.4-.54-.4-.77z" fill="#37474f" />
    <path stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M36 44V33" fill="#b2ff59" stroke="#37474f" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <path d="M27 36h-4V19h-8v17h-4l8 11zm-12 1h1V20h6v17h3.04L19 45.3 12.96 37z" fill="#37474f" />
  </symbol>
  
<symbol id="circle-check" class="icon icon-circle-check"  viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <path d="M335 175L224 286.1L176.1 239c-9.375-9.375-24.56-9.375-33.94 0s-9.375 24.56 0 33.94l64 64C211.7 341.7 217.8 344 224 344s12.28-2.344 16.97-7.031l128-128c9.375-9.375 9.375-24.56 0-33.94S344.4 165.7 335 175zM256 0C114.6 0 0 114.6 0 256s114.6 256 256 256s256-114.6 256-256S397.4 0 256 0zM256 464c-114.7 0-208-93.31-208-208S141.3 48 256 48s208 93.31 208 208S370.7 464 256 464z"></path>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

All in all: either copy viewBox attribute values from symbol to svg instances or define dimensions via css.

Comment: "define dimensions via css" -- this is done. It doesn't fill the parent correctly.

Comment: But you haven't specified a height - therefore you get a fallback height of 150px. I've edited the anwer to clarify this point better