# How to make SVG's width and height of the same as children?

Tags: css, svg, image-scaling

I'm using `<use>` to "grab" a `<symbol>` from an external SVG, the `<use>` element is the right size (100x100), but the `<svg>` still is the default (300x150). Is there any (non-JS) way to make it the child's size in non-hardcoded way?

**HTML:**

```html
<svg><use href="icon.svg#icon" /></svg>
```

**SVG:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
        <rect width="100" height="100" />
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

What I've tried without success:

- `min-content`/`fit-content` `width` and `height`.
- Not using the `<svg>` element and adding `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` on `<use>`.

Comment: add width="100 height="100" to the svg element in HTML

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the "non-hardcoded" part.

Comment: Use whatever makes your content non-hardcoded to non-hardcode everything else then.

Comment: SVG dimensions and HTML dimensions use 2 differents paradygms, SVG is vestor relative coordinates, HTML is about printing.

Comment: 300x150 is an SVG *default* size, just size it with CSS. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KKYmPRG

Comment: The point you're missing: a parent `<svg>`  won't  auto-detect any dimensions or `viewBox`  values from its child elements – that's why you get the fallback dimensions of 300x150px. So you need to either specify the parent svg viewBox (ideally copied from the `<symbol>` definition) or in your case just define an aspect-ratio of 1/1 via css ... or a fixed  width and height. See also ["How to preserve aspect ratio of a SVG symbol?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834684/how-to-preserve-aspect-ratio-of-a-svg-symbol/72840877#72840877)

Comment: In other words: SVG elements don't have intrinsic dimensions like for instance raster images (based on the image pixels) or HTML (styleable via CSS) elements by means of "content-fit"  capabilities. If you haven't defined an appropriate viewBox/width/height you need to run  the nativley browser supported JS method  `getBBox()`  to retrieve viewBox values for "cropping"  the actual visual content.